# Is it possible to select only non repeated number using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my number `1123223` In this number I find the not repetitive at `123` after and before all are under the repetition. how to select only `123` using `regex` is it possible?

I tried it `^(\d)(?!\1{7})\d{7}$` - but not works.

I need to set my input field validation length according to the value I and it's length from server side data.

Comment: Try this: `(\d)(?!\d*\1)`

Comment: If i place `1112356789` it not selecting `6789` instead it selects all. I need to select the longest suitable series

Comment: Why is `23` at the end not in the output?

Comment: @3gwebtrain: Why not `1236789` in `1112356789` if `123` is to be matched in `1123223` ?

Comment: `/(?:(\d)(?!\1))+/`

Comment: @anubhava because it not continue with correct order

Comment: @Barmar - i need to select only ordered values without a break. yours is selecting including the unordered values. `1112356789` here `123` is valid and `56789` as well valid. comparing both 2nd value has higher length. so the result would be `56789`

Comment: I tested it and it returned `12356789`. Why should `123` and `56789` be separate values? There are no duplicates between them.

Comment: Looks like you can use [`[1-9](?:(?<=1)2|(?<=2)3|(?<=3)4|(?<=4)5|(?<=5)6|(?<=6)7|(?<=7)8|(?<=8)9)*`](https://regex101.com/r/ZsJEVd/1) and then sort the matches by length returning the 1st element.

Comment: @Barmar, the `4` is missing it seems. OP is looking for consecutive numbers. And if found, return the longest match....well, that's what I got from the above anyways.

Comment: While it can probably be done like that, regexp is not really an appropriate tool for detecting things like arithmetic sequences. This is much easier in a programming language with loops and arithmetic.

Comment: @JvdV - can you post your comment as answer to accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you can try the following:

```
\d(?:(?<=0)1|(?<=1)2|(?<=2)3|(?<=3)4|(?<=4)5|(?<=5)6|(?<=6)7|(?<=7)8|(?<=8)9)*
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yISwO7/1)

You can apply this pattern to retrieve all matches, then sort the array by length and retrieve the longest match:

```js
const strs = ['12341234','1123223','1112356789','123456789','789123'];
strs.forEach(str => {
    console.log(str.match(/\d(?:(?<=0)1|(?<=1)2|(?<=2)3|(?<=3)4|(?<=4)5|(?<=5)6|(?<=6)7|(?<=7)8|(?<=8)9)*/g).sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0])
})
```